# Flutter: Change text when FlexibleSpaceBar is collapsed

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I have looked through the Flutter documentation to try and find an event, callback or even a state that I could hook into when the FlexibleSpaceBar is collapsed or expanded.

```
return new FlexibleSpaceBar(
  title: new Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
        new Text(_name, style: textTheme.headline),
        new Text(_caption, style: textTheme.caption)
    ]),
  centerTitle: false,
  background: getImage());`
```

When the FlexibleSpaceBar is snapped in (collapsed), I want to hide the **_caption** text and only display the **_name** text. When it is expanded fully, I obviously want to display both **_name** & **_caption**.

How do I go about doing that?

Im new to flutter, so I am somewhat lost on this.

Also reported at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18567

Answer (score 16):

It's not hard to create your own FlexibleSpaceBar.

[image]

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      controller: controller,
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: 220.0,
          floating: true,
          pinned: true,
          elevation: 50,
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          flexibleSpace: _MyAppSpace(),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            List.generate(
              200,
              (index) => Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text('text $index'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _MyAppSpace extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyAppSpace({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, c) {
        final settings = context
            .dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<FlexibleSpaceBarSettings>();
        final deltaExtent = settings.maxExtent - settings.minExtent;
        final t =
            (1.0 - (settings.currentExtent - settings.minExtent) / deltaExtent)
                .clamp(0.0, 1.0) as double;
        final fadeStart = math.max(0.0, 1.0 - kToolbarHeight / deltaExtent);
        const fadeEnd = 1.0;
        final opacity = 1.0 - Interval(fadeStart, fadeEnd).transform(t);

        return Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Opacity(
                  opacity: 1 - opacity,
                  child: getTitle(
                    'Collapsed Title',
                  )),
            ),
            Opacity(
              opacity: opacity,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                children: [
                  getImage(),
                  getTitle(
                    'Expended Title',
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget getImage() {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Image.network(
        'https://source.unsplash.com/daily?code',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getTitle(String text) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(
        text,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 26.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use AnimatedOpacity class.

```
 flexibleSpace:  LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                     var top = constraints.biggest.height;
                      return FlexibleSpaceBar(
                          title: AnimatedOpacity(
                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                               //opacity: top > 71 && top < 91 ? 1.0 : 0.0,                           
                              child: Text(
                               top > 71 && top < 91 ? "Collapse" : "Expanded",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              )),
                          background: Image.network(
                            "https://images.ctfassets.net/pjshm78m9jt4/383122_header/d79a41045d07d114941f7641c83eea6d/importedImage383122_header",
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ));
                    }),
```

Can check original answer from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53380630/9719695

Comment: Wow u saved my time bro

Comment: I would wrap only `AnimatedOpacity` in `LayoutBuilder`, preventing image to re-render on each build. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 7):

It can be done like this :

inside your `initState` method add the scroll listener like that :

```
  ScrollController _controller;
  bool silverCollapsed = false;
  String myTitle = "default title";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = ScrollController();

    _controller.addListener(() {
       if (_controller.offset > 220 && !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
          if(!silverCollapsed){

            // do what ever you want when silver is collapsing !

            myTitle = "silver collapsed !";
            silverCollapsed = true;
            setState(() {});
          }
       }
       if (_controller.offset <= 220 && !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
         if(silverCollapsed){

            // do what ever you want when silver is expanding !

            myTitle = "silver expanded !";
            silverCollapsed = false;
            setState(() {});
         }
       }
    });
 }
```

then wrap your silverAppBar inside `CustomScrollView` and add the controller to this `CustomScrollView` like that :

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       body: CustomScrollView(
          controller: _controller,
          slivers: <Widget>[
             SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 300,
                title: myTitle,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(),
             ),
             SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(<Widget>[
                   // your widgets inside here !
                ]),
             ),
          ],
       ),
    );
}
```

finally change the condition value `_controller.offset > 220` to fit your need !

Answer (score 2):

`FlexibleSpaceBar` per se won't be enough. You need to wrap it into `CustomScrollView` and `SliverAppBar`. These widgets must be controller by a `ScrollController`, which will fire an event whenever scroll offset changes. Based on it, you can find out if app bar is collapsed or expanded, and change the content accordingly. [Here](https://gist.github.com/ianldgs/794884d8837b83fd9c64e06d9b90af4e)  you will find a working example.

Comment: You can also see this question for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942791/how-to-customized-the-sliverappbar-app-bar

Answer (score 1):

Give an height in padding in FlexibleSpaceBar

```
flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 100, // give the value
          title: Text(
            "Test"
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow up to Vishnu Suresh answer:

```
flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
      titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: kToolbarHeight, // give the value
      title: Text(
        "Test"
    ),
```

This will use the appbar height for the padding.