# Creating a Search in appbar that turns into an icon when scrolling down in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have created the Search bar, I need to add a functionality to it so that whenever the user scrolls down, the search bar turns into an icon in the appbar which can be clicked again to expand.

This is the appbar container

```html
Container(
              height: 122,
              color: AppColors.kDefaultPink,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //Location text
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.location_on,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 12.0),
                        Text("Delhi NCR",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                    //SearchBOX
                    SearchBox(onChanged: (value) {}),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

This is the code for the search bar that would be present in the appbar

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:zattireuserapp/views/AppColors.dart';

class SearchBox extends StatelessWidget {

  final ValueChanged onChanged;

  const SearchBox({Key key, this.onChanged}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
      child: Container(
        width: 390,
        height: 45,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
        child: TextField(
          onChanged: onChanged,
          style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.blackColor),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
            hintText: 'Search for anything',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: show some code .

Comment: you can try use sliverappbar widget for that purpose, and get condition from it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372276/flutter-how-to-check-if-sliver-appbar-is-expanded-or-collapsed you may interested check it out.

Comment: @AldyYuan can you please explain about the condition?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LayoutBuilder to get sliver AppBar biggest height. When biggest.height = 80.0, it actually means sliver appbar is collapsed.

Here is a some example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var top = 0.0;
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  
    @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: true);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200.0,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                top = constraints.biggest.height;
                return FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    centerTitle: true,
                    title: top >= 80 ? TextField() : IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () => _scrollController.jumpTo(0)) // condition
                );
              })),
        ];
      },body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return Text("List Item: " + index.toString());
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

I'm sorry for messy code but, I hope you get the idea