# Hide bottom navigation bar when SliverAppBar is min height

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to change positioned of custom bottom navigation bar when my sliverAppBar have to min height.

[Flutter How to check if Sliver AppBar is expanded or collapsed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372276/flutter-how-to-check-if-sliver-appbar-is-expanded-or-collapsed/53376075) - implementation is taken from here

Here is my code

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  bool _headerOpen = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 250,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                  if (constraints.biggest.height -
                          MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top ==
                      kToolbarHeight) {
                    _headerOpen = false;
                  } else {
                    _headerOpen = true;
                  }
                  return FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    title: Text(_headerOpen.toString()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text("Index is " + index.toString());
              },
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: _headerOpen ? 28 : -500,
              child: SafeArea(
                bottom: true,
                child: CustomNavigationBar(
                 // implement of my bottom bar
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think that's because main Widget build is not updated when SliverAppBat change size, but I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm bit confused, do you want to hide it or what ? because your title says you want to hide it.

If you want to hide it, you can use [visibility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) widget. Then wrap your `Position` to this

```
 Visibility(
                  visible: _headerOpen,
                  child: Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: SafeArea(
                      bottom: true,
                      child: CustomNavigationBar(
                          // implement of my bottom bar
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
```