# Custom youtube like appbar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Tried recreating this UI using `SliverAppBar` but without getting scroll info i was not able to update the appbar title according to the position. Is there any other way to do this other than `SliverAppBar` or can i get the scroll position from the sliver to change the state of `AppBar` title accordingly?

[image: App bar design]

Comment: try this Sliverappbar solution [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53380630](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53380630) may it will help u