Flutter Sliver container bouncing effect to fill gap in scroll view
Currently, I'm trying to setup a CustomScrollView along with a Sliver that should stick to the app bar when a user scrolls down and uses the bounces to scroll. It is not possible to make this one app bar here, so I need to use a separate SliverToBoxAdapter under the SliverAppBar.
As expected, when scrolling down on that with the BounceScrollPhysics a white space at the top is visible.

CustomScrollView(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          pinned: true,
          title: const Text('Personal Information'),
          titleTextStyle:
              context.themeData.textTheme.bodyLarge?.bold.copyWith(color: context.themeData.colorScheme.onPrimary),
          backgroundColor: context.themeData.colorScheme.primary,
          foregroundColor: context.themeData.colorScheme.onPrimary,
          centerTitle: true,
          scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
        ),
        const SliverToBoxAdapter(child: _BackgroundCover(height: _backgroundCoverHeight)),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(height: 2000)), // Add some space to make it scrollable. 
      ],
    );


Approach I've tried: Create a custom SliverToBoxAdapter as below and manipulate the childExtent and paintOrigin based on the scroll position.

class RenderStretchableSliverToBoxAdapter extends RenderSliverSingleBoxAdapter {
  /// Creates a [RenderSliver] that wraps a [RenderBox] with a stretchable extent.
  RenderStretchableSliverToBoxAdapter({
    super.child,
    required this.childExtent,
  });

  final double childExtent;

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    var currentChildExtent = childExtent;

    if (child == null) {
      geometry = SliverGeometry.zero;
      return;
    }

    // Obtain the sliver constraints.
    final constraints = this.constraints;

    // If there's an overlap at the top, we calculate the `inversedOverlap` to update the new [childExtent].
    final inversedOverlap = min(0, constraints.overlap) * -1;
    currentChildExtent += inversedOverlap;

    // The sliver will be created from the overlap instead of the 0.0.
    final paintOrigin = constraints.overlap;

    // Calculate with the new [paintOrigin].
    final paintedChildSize = calculatePaintOffset(constraints, from: paintOrigin, to: currentChildExtent);
    final cacheExtent = calculateCacheOffset(constraints, from: paintOrigin, to: currentChildExtent);

    // Set the updated childExtent as the minHeight for the button.
    child!.layout(constraints.asBoxConstraints().copyWith(minHeight: currentChildExtent), parentUsesSize: true);

    // Finally set the geometry and update the parent data.
    geometry = SliverGeometry(
      scrollExtent: currentChildExtent,
      paintExtent: paintedChildSize,
      paintOrigin: paintOrigin,
      cacheExtent: cacheExtent,
      maxPaintExtent: currentChildExtent,
      hitTestExtent: paintedChildSize,
    );

    setChildParentData(child!, constraints, geometry!);
  }
}


The above solution however gives a laggy effect as shown below:
What could be the cause of this and any recommendations here?

not sure I understand what you want, but maybe look at this? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverPersistentHeader-class.html

Thanks for the reply! What I'm trying to get is basically the stretch effect as is done when you use SliverAppBar(stretch: true) but then in a SliverToBoxAdapter. It seems to work, but I'm not sure if my implementation is correct performance wise as it seems a bit laggy.

You can have multiple sliverappbars if you set primary: false, But check this page for all the available slivers https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView/slivers.html Did you try your solution with a release build in a physical device? Debug builds and emulators are laggy.

Or maybe you can have multiple primary appbars, try it out. I have used multiple appbars a few times, I just don't remember how they behaved.

That is true indeed, but with multiple app bars the stretch effect does not work as expected. The problem is that:

The Sliver should support the stretch the SliverAppBar has, in other words it should fill the blank area that's created when the user scrolls down
The Sliver should scroll under the app bar as a default app bar


I'm not sure what you want I'm not an expert in slivers, maybe a video would help me understand. But I have managed to do some customizations with scrollcontroller and setstate, just by changing the properties of the appbars during scroll. Also try your current solution on a real device with a release build. Looking at your code it doesn't seem like a slow widget.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372276/flutter-how-to-check-if-sliver-appbar-is-expanded-or-collapsed
